# How to push changes to Kubernestes Kube-proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

I'm new to Kubernetes development, and I have a task to change some features in Kuberenetes services.

I have the [Kubernetes local cluster](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/tree/master/contributors/devel#readme), and also I have a testbed consisting of 4 RPI's, My first changes were done over `Kubectl`, and what I have done was cross compiling the binaries on my machine and then replacing the old binaries found in the RPI's (since compiling the code in  the RPI's is time-consuming).

Now, I have reached a point where I have to update some changes to `Kube-proxy`, in the local cluster the binary files are in `_output/bin`, however in the real cluster the Kube-proxy is running in a container (for each node), so changing the binaries would need creating new Docker images and forcing Kubernetes to choose those images instead of the default ones (as far as I understood).

So My questions:

1. What is the best/easiest way to push the changes on `Kube-proxy` on the running cluster?
2. If I compiled the code in the RPI, the `make` will release a binary file of `Kube-proxy`, but how the cluster will take those changes?

Cluster Spec's:

1. Kubernetes v1.9.
2. OS hypriotos-v7+.
3. Architecture arm 32-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All nodes should run kube-proxy. (Running kube-proxy on a “master” node is not strictly required, but being consistent is easier.) Obtain a binary as described for kubelet.

Arguments to consider:

If following the HTTPS security approach:

```
--master=https://$MASTER_IP
--kubeconfig=/var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig
```

Otherwise, if taking the firewall-based security approach

```
--master=http://$MASTER_IP
```

Note that on some Linux platforms, you may need to manually install the conntrack package which is a dependency of kube-proxy, or else kube-proxy cannot be started successfully.

For more details on debugging kube-proxy problems, please refer to Debug Services

Source : https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/#kube-proxy